# How can Bootstrap scrollspy realize the function of adding the given class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I had realized the basic function of scrollspy .
The navbar  has the active effects.
But I want to realize that when we at the top of the page, 
The nav  has the class of "navbar-yellow-style".
After scroll some pixels , the class of nav will became "navbar-transparant-style" , so it can become transpant.
How to realize it with scrollspy?
If not, how can I realize it with other mothods?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understand that the Scrollspy of Bootstrap it not used for adding the given class to some divs .but to active the nav part.
To realize this function I can code like this

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
               if($("body").scrollTop() >= 100){
                    $("#navbar").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
                   console.log("suc");
               }
               if($("body").scrollTop() < 100){
                    $("#navbar").addClass("navbar-fixed-top");
               }
    })
```

so I can also check the offset of given tags and realize it .
`$(selector).offset().top`